# Amazon Route 53 www record

Tags: amazon-route53

I'm looking to move our current dns to route 53 due to some limitations with our provider.

Currently we have A records with network solutions for:

- www
- @ (None)
- * (All others)
- other subdomains...

From intial looks at the route 53 interface there doesnt seem to be any built in option to specify the www, @ or * records, do I still need to create these, and if so what is the best way to do it.

Comment: Am I missing something here? You go in the web console and create records for each.

Comment: sorry I know how to acutally add the records, I was more meaning that if I enter an @ or a * will they actually work as they do with my current provider network solutions

Comment: Yah. They will!

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon Route 53 UI is a little tricky. It's not immediately clear from certain elements whether you can click on them. A *wider* browser window is handy when making entries.

From the "Create Record Set" option, the **Name** field to the left of the domain name is the next place you want make changes. And then from there, work down the page to enter your values.

[image]

A completed record...

[image]

Comment: please see my comment above

Comment: Yes. See [Amazon's FAQ - **Support for wildcard entries**](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#Support_for_wildcard_entries)

Answer (score 0):

First read [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewDNS.html#NewDNSAddRecords).

1. Click on **Go to Record Sets**.

   [image]
2. Click on **Create Record Set**.

   [image]
3. Enter in the appropriate values.

Comment: please see my comment above